# MS Excel VBA to Export to PDF Terminates Suddenly and forces computer to reboot

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have some VBA code (see below) that basically prints named ranges in an excel file to PDF.
I have command buttons for each macro and It works fine, but when i'm printing them sequentially you (group1, group2, group3....) when i get to group6 
the file just suddenly closes and forces the computer to restart???

what am i doing wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Cris

---

```
Option Explicit


Sub Print_Group1()

Dim r As Range
Dim fDrive As String
fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportGroups").Activate
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportGroups").Range("Groups_Reports")
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Index").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub Print_Group2()

Dim r As Range
Dim fDrive As String
fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Activate
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("All_Reports")
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group2.pdf.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Index").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub Print_Group3()

Dim r As Range
Dim fDrive As String
fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Activate

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000001, Report___000002, Report___000003, Report___000004, Report___000005, Report___000006")
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000007, Report___000008, Report___000009, Report___000010, Report___000011"))
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000012, Report___000013, Report___000014, Report___000015, Report___000016"))
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group3.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Index").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub


Sub Print_Group4()

Dim r As Range
Dim fDrive As String
fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Activate

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000017, Report___000018, Report___000019, Report___000020")
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000021, Report___000022, Report___000023, Report___000024"))
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000025, Report___000026, Report___000027, Report___000028"))
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group4.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Index").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub Print_Group5()

Dim r As Range
Dim fDrive As String
fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Activate

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000029, Report___000030, Report___000031, Report___000032, Report___000033, Report___000034")
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000035, Report___000036, Report___000037, Report___000038, Report___000039, Report___000040"))
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000041, Report___000042, Report___000043, Report___000044, Report___000045"))
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group5.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Index").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub Print_Group6()

Dim r As Range
Dim fDrive As String
fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Activate

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000046, Report___000047, Report___000048, Report___000049, Report___000050, Report___000051, Report___000052, Report___000053")
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000054, Report___000055, Report___000056, Report___000057, Report___000058, Report___000059, Report___000060, Report___000061"))
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000062, Report___000063, Report___000064, Report___000065, Report___000066, Report___000067"))
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group6.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Index").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub Print_Group7()

Dim r As Range
Dim fDrive As String
fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Activate

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000068, Report___000069, Report___000070, Report___000071")
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000072, Report___000073, Report___000074, Report___000075"))
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000076, Report___000077, Report___000078, Report___000079"))
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group7.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Index").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub Print_Group8()

Dim r As Range
Dim fDrive As String
fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Activate

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000080, Report___000081, Report___000082, Report___000083")
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000084, Report___000085, Report___000086"))
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("Report___000087, Report___000088, Report___000089"))
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group8.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Index").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is that the process of creating the PDF is taking up the memory and the next is starting before the previous is finished, You will need to put in a wait or do events to slow down the code to wait for each pdf to be created before starting the next code.

Comment: @ScottCraner - there's a `MsgBox()` call at the end of each `Sub`. Unless the process is _really_ slow (saving via tin-can-and-twine network to northern Siberia), it should be completed by the time the user has clicked OK. Plus, this is VBA `.ExportAsFixedFormat` isn't going to run in a background thread, is it? Heck, manually clicking "save" will block the VBE while the file is saving...

Comment: @FreeMan it's completed by the time the `.Save` method returns and the `MsgBox` is even shown

Comment: Well I did say it was a guess. :)

Comment: Have you tried this with `OpenAfterPublish:=False`? That would help narrow down whether it's an Excel issue or a PDF reader issue.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't solve your problem, but it will make your code *much* more maintainable.

```
Public Sub PrintReportGroup(ByVal groupID As Long, ByVal startReport As Long, ByVal endReport As Long)

'consider making this a named range too!
  Dim fDrive As String
  fDrive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("S3").value

'you're working with named sheets, you don't need to .Activate them
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Activate

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports")
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = startReport To endReport
      Dim reportRange As Range
      Set reportRange = Union(reportRange, .Range("reportReport___" & CStr(Format(counter, "000000"))))
    Next
  End With

  reportRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                        fDrive & "MyReports\PDF_Reports\Group" & CStr(groupID) & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

'You'll still be on the sheet you started with, so no need to return "home"    
'Worksheets("Index").Activate
'Not sure why you're saving here - nothing you did during printing needs a save, but, this could be an oddly placed save for other changes made.
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
'get rid of this MsgBox once it's all working ok
  MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Now you have one procedure that you can call to make several PDFs:

```
Public Sub PrintReports()
  PrintReportGroup 3, 1, 16
  PrintReportGroup 4, 17, 28
  PrintReportGroup 5, 29, 45
  PrintReportGroup 6, 46, 67
  'etc...
End Sub
```

It also makes it easy to debug by modifying the `PrintReportGroup 6, 46 67` line. Change that to

```
PrintReportGroup 6, 46, 46
```

and see if it works. If so, change it to

```
PrintReportGroup 6, 46, 47
```

and keep going until it blows up. I'm guessing that *either* there's a missing named range, or you typed one of the named ranges incorrectly, or you're hitting some sort of limit in the PDF builder that it doesn't like.

Also, try Comintern's suggestion of including `OpenAfterPublish:=False`. Added bonus, you'll only have to put it in 1 place to change *all* your code!